# SQL how to get parent and its all children and children of children... etc

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have to see I am new to sql.

I have a table which looks like this:

```
child      parent
-------------------
Nancy      Bob
Oli        Bob
Alice      Oli
Mira      Alice
```

Now I need sql statement which gives me parent -which is already known- and its children and children of its children... etc, given is parent name.

Example I need Family of `Bob`. The sql should return `(Bob, Nancy, Oli, Alice, Mira)`

I tried this: `select child from myTable where parent='Bob'` This gives me Nancy and Oli.

Any Idea?

Comment: Use a recursive cte. (WITH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Oracle's hierarchial queries to get this along with the level of tree:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f615ab/4)

```
SELECT CHILD,  LEVEL FROM TABLE1
START WITH PARENT = 'Bob'
connect by prior child = parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s a typical hierarchical query. One standard method uses a recursive `with` clause:

```
with cte (child, parent) as (
    select child, parent from mytable where parent = 'Bob'
    union all
    select t.child, t.parent
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on c.child = t.parent
)
select child from cte
```